# Where can I find the GOG version of Torchlight 2's save folder under Linux?

Tags: linux, torchlight-2, gog

I'm playing *Torchlight 2* and want to backup my save but I don't know where to find the savegame folder. Under Windows, it was something like `C:\Documents\My Games\`, etc.

I found this webpage: https://savelocation.net/torchlight2 - but it doesn't help me because it only lists the save folder for the Steam version. I use GOG and not Steam.

Comment: Have you tried `find ~ -type d -iname "*torchlight*"`?

Comment: You can also try `locate torchlight`

Comment: Is it in your home folder? Make sure you have all files shown and look for a .torchlight folder or something

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, with my current reputation I can't add a comment under your question, so if you already did what I will mention now, I will delete this answer.

---

Did you have a look at [this](https://www.gog.com/forum/torchlight_series/failure_transferring_save_games_to_linux_from_windows_version/post4)? Someone wanted to transfer his Windows save file(s) to the Linux version and wrote that it worked when he put them into `~/.local/share/Runic Games/Torchlight 2/save/`.

If that did not work then according to [this post](https://www.gog.com/forum/serpent_in_the_staglands/linux_save_file_location/post2) you could look into the `~/.config/unity3d/` folder.

If it is not there either, you could try out a search program, like catfish, and search for the name "save".